# Organizing the output of my shell script into tables within the text file

Tags: shell, unix, text-files, bioinformatics, genome

I am working with a unix shell script that does genome construction then creates a phylogeny. Depending on the genome assembler you use, the final output (the phylogeny) may change. I wish to compare the effects of using various genome assemblers. I have developed some metrics to compare them on, but I need help organizing them so I can run useful analyses. I would like to import my data into excel in columns.

This is the script I am using to output data:

```
echo "Enter the size (Mb or Gb) of your data set:"
read SIZEOFDATASET
echo "The size of your data set is $SIZEOFDATASET"
echo "Size of Data Set:" >> metrics_file.txt 
echo $SIZEOFDATASET >> metrics_file.txt

echo "Enter the name of your assembler"
read NAMEOFASSEMBLER
echo "You are using $NAMEOFASSEMBLER as your assembler"
echo "Name of Assembler:" >> metrics_file.txt 
echo "$NAMEOFASSEMBLER" >> metrics_file.txt
echo "Time:" >> metrics_file.txt
```

The output comes out like this currently:

```
Size of Data Set:
387 Mb
Name of Assembler:
Velvet
Genome Size:
1745690
Time:
```

I want it to look something like this:
[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you please post the script?

Comment: remove that image and paste the actual output text. I can't copy it like this

Comment: Ok, sorry I forgot to do that. It is there now.

Answer (score 7):

```
#!/bin/sh

in_file=in.txt      # Input file
params=3            # Parameters count
res_file=$(mktemp)  # Temporary file
sep=' '             # Separator character

# Print header
cnt=0
for i in $(cat $in_file | head -$((params*2))); do
    if [ $((cnt % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $i
    fi
    cnt=$((cnt+1))
done | sed ":a;N;\$!ba;s/\n/$sep/g" >>$res_file

# Parse and print values
cnt=0
for i in $(cat $in_file); do
    # Print values, skip param names
    if [ $((cnt % 2)) -eq 1 ]; then
        echo -n $i >>$res_file
    fi

    if [ $(((cnt+1) % (params*2))) -eq 0 ]; then
        # Values line is finished, print newline
        echo >>$res_file
    elif [ $((cnt % 2)) -eq 1 ]; then
        # More values expected to be printed on this line
        echo -n "$sep" >>$res_file
    fi

    cnt=$((cnt+1))
done

# Make nice table format
cat $res_file | column -t
rm -f $res_file
```

### Explanation

This scripts assumes that:

- input file is called "in.txt" (see **in_file** variable)
- input file uses format you described in question
- result table should have 3 columns (see **params** variable)

Most of the code is just parsing of your input data format. Actual column formatting is done by `column` tool.

If you want to export this table to excel, just change **sep** variable to `','` and save result output to **.csv** file. This file can be easily imported in excel application.

### Example

Input file:

```
Size
387
Name
Velvet
Time
13
Size
31415
Name
Minia
Time
18
Size
31337
Name
ABCDEF
Time
42
```

Script output:

```
Size   Name    Time
387    Velvet  13
31415  Minia   18
31337  ABCDEF  42
```

Answer (score 1):

Sam's answer provided exactly what you are looking for, but you can also consider making it more streamlined, avoiding the need to convert the metrics file into a table, and just write the table right away.  For example, write a single script like this, user_input.bash:

```
echo "Enter the size (Mb or Gb) of your data set:" > /dev/stderr
read SIZEOFDATASET
echo "The size of your data set is $SIZEOFDATASET" > /dev/stderr
echo "Enter the name of your assembler" > /dev/stderr
read NAMEOFASSEMBLER
echo "You are using $NAMEOFASSEMBLER as your assembler" > /dev/stderr
echo "Enter Time:" > /dev/stderr
read TIME
echo "You entered Time:" $TIME > /dev/stderr
echo "Name Size Time"
echo $NAMEOFASSEMBLER $SIZEOFDATASET $TIME
```

To use program:

```
 ./user_input.bash > metrics.file.1.txt
    ./user_input.bash > metrics.file.2.txt
    ./user_input.bash > metrics.file.3.txt
    ...
```

The collect all results:

```
head -n 1  metrics.file.1.txt > allmetrics.txt
tail -n +2 -q metrics.file.*.txt > allmetrics.txt
```

HTH

Comment: I will try this too, streamline is definitely a good thing for the project I am working on, thank you!