# how to use shell script to convert row to column or some nice table

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I got the following script from [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28755377/469210) :

```
#!/bin/sh

in_file=temp2.txt   # Input file
params=6            # Parameters count
res_file=$(mktemp)  # Temporary file
sep=' '             # Separator character

# Print header
cnt=0
for i in $(cat $in_file | head -$((params*2))); do
    if [ $((cnt % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $i
    fi
    cnt=$((cnt+1))
done | sed ":a;N;\$!ba;s/\n/$sep/g" >>$res_file

# Parse and print values
cnt=0
for i in $(cat $in_file); do
    # Print values, skip param names
    if [ $((cnt % 2)) -eq 1 ]; then
        echo -n $i >>$res_file
    fi

    if [ $(((cnt+1) % (params*2))) -eq 0 ]; then
        # Values line is finished, print newline
        echo >>$res_file
    elif [ $((cnt % 2)) -eq 1 ]; then
        # More values expected to be printed on this line
        echo -n "$sep" >>$res_file
    fi

    cnt=$((cnt+1))
done

# Make nice table format
cat $res_file | column -t
#rm -f $res_file
```

But then i have about 100 + lines in it and i'm getting a error**"column: line too long"** as below :

> ****column: line too long**** GigabitEthernet0/0     GigabitEthernet1/0/3   GigabitEthernet1/0/5   GigabitEthernet1/0/10 
>   GigabitEthernet1/0/19  GigabitEthernet1/0/33 GigabitEthernet1/0/2
>   GigabitEthernet1/0/4   GigabitEthernet1/0/7   GigabitEthernet1/0/18 
>   GigabitEthernet1/0/30  GigabitEthernet1/0/44 GigabitEthernet1/0/46 
>   GigabitEthernet1/1/3   GigabitEthernet2/0/1   GigabitEthernet2/0/5
>   GigabitEthernet2/0/9   GigabitEthernet2/0/14 GigabitEthernet2/0/18 
>   GigabitEthernet2/0/31  GigabitEthernet2/0/34  GigabitEthernet2/0/36 
>   GigabitEthernet2/0/40  GigabitEthernet2/1/3 GigabitEthernet3/0/12 
>   GigabitEthernet3/0/30  GigabitEthernet3/0/32  GigabitEthernet3/0/34 
>   GigabitEthernet3/0/36  GigabitEthernet3/0/38 GigabitEthernet3/0/40 
>   GigabitEthernet3/0/42  GigabitEthernet3/0/44  GigabitEthernet3/0/46 
>   GigabitEthernet3/0/48  GigabitEthernet3/1/2

Any solutions you can give, i could not find the author of this script again here to ask him on this can be avoided.

Input file will be something like this :

{
GigabitEthernet0/0
GigabitEthernet1/0/2
GigabitEthernet1/0/3
GigabitEthernet1/0/4
GigabitEthernet1/0/5
GigabitEthernet1/0/7
GigabitEthernet1/0/10
GigabitEthernet1/0/18
GigabitEthernet1/0/19
GigabitEthernet1/0/30
GigabitEthernet1/0/33
GigabitEthernet1/0/44
GigabitEthernet1/0/45
GigabitEthernet1/0/46
GigabitEthernet1/1/2
GigabitEthernet1/1/3
GigabitEthernet1/1/4
GigabitEthernet2/0/1
GigabitEthernet2/0/2
GigabitEthernet2/0/5
GigabitEthernet2/0/8
GigabitEthernet2/0/9
GigabitEthernet2/0/12
GigabitEthernet2/0/14
GigabitEthernet2/0/15
GigabitEthernet2/0/18
GigabitEthernet2/0/22
GigabitEthernet2/0/31
GigabitEthernet2/0/33
GigabitEthernet2/0/34
GigabitEthernet2/0/35
GigabitEthernet2/0/36
GigabitEthernet2/0/38
GigabitEthernet2/0/40
GigabitEthernet2/1/2
GigabitEthernet2/1/3
GigabitEthernet2/1/4
GigabitEthernet3/0/12
GigabitEthernet3/0/23
GigabitEthernet3/0/30
GigabitEthernet3/0/31
GigabitEthernet3/0/32
GigabitEthernet3/0/33
GigabitEthernet3/0/34
GigabitEthernet3/0/35
GigabitEthernet3/0/36
GigabitEthernet3/0/37
GigabitEthernet3/0/38
GigabitEthernet3/0/39
GigabitEthernet3/0/40
GigabitEthernet3/0/41
GigabitEthernet3/0/42
GigabitEthernet3/0/43
GigabitEthernet3/0/44
GigabitEthernet3/0/45
GigabitEthernet3/0/46
GigabitEthernet3/0/47
GigabitEthernet3/0/48
GigabitEthernet3/1/1
GigabitEthernet3/1/2
GigabitEthernet3/1/3
GigabitEthernet3/1/4
}

Output i need something like this :

{
GigabitEthernet0/0   | GigabitEthernet1/0/33 |
GigabitEthernet1/0/2 | GigabitEthernet1/0/44 |
GigabitEthernet1/0/3 | GigabitEthernet1/0/43 |
GigabitEthernet1/0/4 | GigabitEthernet1/0/46 |
GigabitEthernet1/0/5 | GigabitEthernet1/1/2  |
GigabitEthernet1/0/7 | GigabitEthernet1/1/3  |
GigabitEthernet1/0/10| GigabitEthernet1/1/4  |
GigabitEthernet1/0/18| GigabitEthernet2/0/1  |
GigabitEthernet1/0/19| GigabitEthernet2/0/2  |
GigabitEthernet1/0/30| GigabitEthernet2/0/5  |
}

Comment: Please update your question with the input file and expected output.

Comment: That's a *horrendous* script.

Comment: I may have to agree with tripleee on this one. Certainly with oliv. Please show examples of desired in and out. I'm pretty sure we can do better than this. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have got this resolved using a column command.

it just posts the output something like this

`column  vacant_temp4.txt
GigabitEthernet1/0/1    GigabitEthernet1/0/48   GigabitEthernet2/0/34   GigabitEthernet3/0/44   GigabitEthernet4/0/28
GigabitEthernet1/0/2    GigabitEthernet1/1/2    GigabitEthernet2/0/35   GigabitEthernet3/1/1    GigabitEthernet4/0/29
GigabitEthernet1/0/3    GigabitEthernet1/1/3    GigabitEthernet2/0/36   GigabitEthernet3/1/2    GigabitEthernet4/0/30
GigabitEthernet1/0/5    GigabitEthernet1/1/4    GigabitEthernet2/0/38   GigabitEthernet3/1/3    GigabitEthernet4/0/31
GigabitEthernet1/0/7    GigabitEthernet2/0/1    GigabitEthernet2/0/45   GigabitEthernet3/1/4    GigabitEthernet4/0/32
GigabitEthernet1/0/8    GigabitEthernet2/0/5    GigabitEthernet2/1/2    GigabitEthernet4/0/1    GigabitEthernet4/0/33
GigabitEthernet1/0/9    GigabitEthernet2/0/8    GigabitEthernet2/1/3    GigabitEthernet4/0/5    GigabitEthernet4/0/34
GigabitEthernet1/0/14   GigabitEthernet2/0/9    GigabitEthernet2/1/4    GigabitEthernet4/0/6    GigabitEthernet4/0/35
GigabitEthernet1/0/16   GigabitEthernet2/0/10   GigabitEthernet3/0/2    GigabitEthernet4/0/9    GigabitEthernet4/0/36
GigabitEthernet1/0/19   GigabitEthernet2/0/13   GigabitEthernet3/0/5    GigabitEthernet4/0/12   GigabitEthernet4/0/37
GigabitEthernet1/0/20   GigabitEthernet2/0/14   GigabitEthernet3/0/7    GigabitEthernet4/0/13   GigabitEthernet4/0/38
GigabitEthernet1/0/26   GigabitEthernet2/0/16   GigabitEthernet3/0/13   GigabitEthernet4/0/16   GigabitEthernet4/0/39
GigabitEthernet1/0/27   GigabitEthernet2/0/20   GigabitEthernet3/0/16   GigabitEthernet4/0/17   GigabitEthernet4/0/40
GigabitEthernet1/0/28   GigabitEthernet2/0/21   GigabitEthernet3/0/19   GigabitEthernet4/0/18   GigabitEthernet4/0/41
GigabitEthernet1/0/30   GigabitEthernet2/0/25   GigabitEthernet3/0/22   GigabitEthernet4/0/19   GigabitEthernet4/0/42
GigabitEthernet1/0/31   GigabitEthernet2/0/26   GigabitEthernet3/0/25   GigabitEthernet4/0/20   GigabitEthernet4/1/1
GigabitEthernet1/0/35   GigabitEthernet2/0/27   GigabitEthernet3/0/26   GigabitEthernet4/0/21   GigabitEthernet4/1/2
GigabitEthernet1/0/36   GigabitEthernet2/0/28   GigabitEthernet3/0/27   GigabitEthernet4/0/22   GigabitEthernet4/1/3
GigabitEthernet1/0/37   GigabitEthernet2/0/29   GigabitEthernet3/0/37   GigabitEthernet4/0/23   GigabitEthernet4/1/4
GigabitEthernet1/0/40   GigabitEthernet2/0/30   GigabitEthernet3/0/39   GigabitEthernet4/0/24
GigabitEthernet1/0/45   GigabitEthernet2/0/31   GigabitEthernet3/0/41   GigabitEthernet4/0/26
GigabitEthernet1/0/46   GigabitEthernet2/0/32   GigabitEthernet3/0/42   GigabitEthernet4/0/27`

It looked better than what you saw above on my putty screen .

Thank you oliv , tripleee , paul & all.